# How to redirect a link to another page on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

i would like to know where do i change a link to direct to another page, if you look into my website http://www.ker-downeyafrica.com/southern-africa/ there's a green small block which says "enquire now" it is there in almost every page, when you click on it a modal dialog box pops up but i want to change it to go to the enquire now page (last page on the main menu)

I had a look i see its been called from somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is coming from a standard template so you would have to have a look in the page templates.

Try looking at page.php and do a search for:

```
<div class="destination_landing_enquire">
```

That should hopefully show you where to make the changes.
Then where you find:

```
<a class="cufon-link enquiry-lb cboxElement" href="http://www.ker-downeyafrica.com/enquire-now-form/?subject=">
```

change the href="" attribute to the link you want to go to.

You will also need to remove the cboxElement class from the  class section.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've noticed, the "enquire now"button is most of the page but not in all of them so now i'm trying to figure out which tamplete file/page it is in.

Comment: and also i looked at the destination templete file here the piece of code that they used  <a class="cufon-link enquiry-lb" href="<?php print KD_ENQUIRE_URL . '?subject=' . urlencode($title) ?>"><?php print $kd_texts['enquire'] ?></a>   so its calling the url from somewhere

Comment: KD_ENQUIRE_URL will be most like defined in the themes functions.php file. If you do a search in there you could replace the url or replace  everything in the href for something like:href="<?php print  $site_url ;?>'/enquire-now'"

Comment: no not yet, looks like  this is part of the theme and its a bit of a bother to go through a lot of source code to make all of the changes, but i'm busy trying to redirect the link using javascript but hasn't worked yet.